# ServiceStack: Installing 'ServiceStack.HttpClient' in a Blazor project adds hundreds of dependencies?

Tags: nuget, servicestack, blazor

I am doing some testing with Blazor, and since its C# I thought I could add the ServiceStack.HttpClient to use when talking to the backend.

However, when I saw that dependencies that NuGet was about to install, I got a bit scared, so I just wanted to check if this is normal and expected. We're talking about hundreds of added references.

[image]

Does this seem reasonable? `runtime.fedora...Cryptography...`?

Comment: Never heard of ServiceStack. But I wonder how can ServiceStack.HttpClient be used on Blazor client-side ?

Comment: Well, if Blazor allows for using C# code, then why not, is what I asked myself. ServiceStack is a great lib, and being able to use it for the C# parts in Blazor would be pure greatness. Im not sure why it wouldnt work to be honest...

Answer (score 1):

Most of these are transitive dependencies of ASP.NET Core dependencies.

You can view the list of dependencies of each package on NuGet:

[ServiceStack.HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.HttpClient/):

```
ServiceStack.Client (>= 5.5.0)
ServiceStack.Interfaces (>= 5.5.0)
ServiceStack.Text (>= 5.5.0)
System.Collections.Specialized (>= 4.3.0)
System.Net.Requests (>= 4.3.0)
System.ServiceModel.Primitives (>= 4.5.3)
System.Xml.XmlSerializer (>= 4.3.0)
```

[ServiceStack.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Client):

```
ServiceStack.Interfaces (>= 5.5.0)
ServiceStack.Text (>= 5.5.0)
System.Collections.Specialized (>= 4.3.0)
System.Memory (>= 4.5.2)
System.Net.Requests (>= 4.3.0)
System.ServiceModel.Primitives (>= 4.5.3)
System.Xml.XmlSerializer (>= 4.3.0)
```

[ServiceStack.Text](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text/):

```
Microsoft.CSharp (>= 4.5.0)
System.Memory (>= 4.5.2)
System.Runtime (>= 4.3.0)
```

[ServiceStack.Interfaces](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Interfaces/):

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)
```